# How to get the items inside an array in Object Oriented PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have the following variable available inside a view:

```
$recent_posts
```

It is an array so I performed a foreach loop on it and var dumped the result like so:

```
<? foreach($recent_posts as $post): ?>

<pre><?= var_dump($post) ?></pre>

<? endforeach ?>
```

This is the output I received from the vardump:

```
Array
(
    [obj] => models\Tag Object
        (
            [large_image:protected] => 
            [small_image:protected] => 
            [_obj_id] => 13493
            [_validator] => 
            [_values:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_dirty_values:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_type:protected] => 
            [_properties:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [_is_loaded:protected] => 
            [_is_static:protected] => 
        )

)
```

How can I retrieve the values for each post. For example how can I get the `large_image` for a post? I tried this (without knowing what the heck I'm doing) and not surprisingly it didn't work:

```
<?= $post->large_image ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`large_image` is `protected`, you cannot access `protected` `members` out side of the class (`this` context).

You have two options, add a `getter` function for `large_image` or make it `public`.

`getter` is a function that exposes `private` or `protected` member, for example

```
public function get_large_image(){
   return $this->large_image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$post->large_image` is a protected property, you are not allowed to access it outside of the class (or derived classes). I presume there might be a getter method by which you will be able to retrieve the value though (something like `get_large_image()` perhaps).

To determine what methods are available on the object, either view the source code of the accompanying class, or use reflection:

```
$refl = new ReflectionClass( $post );
var_dump( $refl->getMethods() );
```

If there's no method available to get the value, I would not advise you to alter the class, by making the property public (it's been made protected for a reason I presume), or alter the class at all, if it is not your own.

Rather, I would suggest, if possible, you extend the class and create a getter method for the value:

```
<?php

class MyTag
    extends Tag
{
    // I would personally prefer camelCase: getLargeImage
    // but this might be more in line with the signature of the original class
    public function get_large_image()
    {
        return $this->large_image;
    }
}
```

Of course, this will get tricky soon, if you don't have the means to control the instantiation of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

`$post['obj']->large_image` should do it.

That property is protected so you may not have access unless you are in the class.

Comment: he cannot access the this member because he is not in `this` context